# Unexpected token ... - VS code with prettier

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

To auto format my react code using prettier, I have used to configure format on save in VS code settings.

It worked fine with my basic template code.

When i have used spread operator: ... in my code,

From then onwards, it is not formatting code on save and showing error in console as:

```js
"prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
 "editor.formatOnSave": true
```

How to make prettier + eslint to work fine with ... (spread operator) in vs code.

So that it can format on save instead of showing error.